# Empezar a agregar la informacion de mi JTable enviada a Excel desde una fila en especifico

Tags: java, mysql, excel, apache, apache-poi

Buen dia, estoy realizando un sistema en JAVA, en el cual el usuario puede generar archivos excel con un formato ya establecido, el problema surge cuando quiero que la informacion de mi JTable se agregue desde una fila en especifico hacia abajo, ya que por defecto se agrega desde el principio del archivo excel y en las primeras filas ya tengo informacion. Este es el archivo Excel:
[image: Archivo Excel Generado]

Como pueden ver quiero que la informacion del jtable se empiece a registrar desde la fila 13 para abajo, pero empieza agregarse desde arriba y sobreescribe encima de lo que ya esta registrado, les dejo el codigo donde recorro mi JTable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tablaDestino.getRowCount()-1; i++) {
            XSSFRow fila = sheet.createRow(i);           
            if(i==0){
                for (int j = 0; j < tablaDestino.getColumnCount()-1; j++) {
                    XSSFCell celda = fila.createCell(j);
                    celda.setCellValue(new XSSFRichTextString(tablaDestino.getColumnModel().getColumn(j).getHeaderValue().toString()));
                }
            }else{
                for (int j = 0; j < tablaDestino.getColumnCount()-1; j++) {
                    XSSFCell celda = fila.createCell(j);
                    if(tablaDestino.getValueAt(i, j)!=null)
                        celda.setCellValue(new XSSFRichTextString(tablaDestino.getValueAt(i, j).toString()));
                }
            }
            }
```

Muchisimas Gracias por su tiempo... Saludos....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucione, necesitaba otro contador para la ubicacion del registro!! en caso de que le sirva a alguien :

```
Row rowCol = sheet.createRow(12);
            //ciclo para recorrer las columnas de mi JTable "tablaDestino" y psar esa info a excel
            //recorremos las columnas de mi tabla 

            for (int i = 0; i < tablaDestino.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                //creamos la celda en excel
                org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell cell = rowCol.createCell(i);
                //Asignamos el valor de la columna del jtable a mi archivo excel 
                cell.setCellValue(tablaDestino.getColumnName(i));
            }
            //ciclo para recorrer las filas de JTable "tabladestino"
            //mi variable j es la que se encargara de darle la posicion en excel al jtable
            int j = 12;
            for (int m = 0; m < tablaDestino.getRowCount(); m++) {
                //creamos la fila y se va incrementando 
                Row row = sheet.createRow(j++); //el j++ va incrementando desde el 12 en adelante para posicionar bien mi jtable 
                //ciclo tomar datos de tabladestino y hacerles set en el archivo excel
                for (int k = 0; k < tablaDestino.getColumnCount(); k++) {
                    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell cell = row.createCell(k);
                    if (tablaDestino.getValueAt(m, k) != null) {
                        cell.setCellValue(tablaDestino.getValueAt(m, k).toString());

                    }
                }
            }
```